# Forcasting Data with Arima Model in R

Tags: r, forecasting, predict, arima

I am a beginner in the R language, I have a monthly data list for requests received quantities by product, how I can make the forecast with ARIMA model (best model) can any kind of data.
I used the code below but I don’t know if the results are correct and reliable or I have to change another model or a simple change in this code.

Script :

```
#Step 1: Plot Qty data as time series

data <- structure(c(3108L, 2508L, 3516L, 3828L, 3755L, 6612L, 6708L, 
  3624L, 4032L, 4104L, 3000L, 3204L, 2640L, 2124L, 1884L, 12382L, 
  1488L, 1356L, 2028L, 1764L, 1524L, 7248L, 1248L, 816L, 804L, 
  708L, 756L, 972L, 4104L, 1296L, 2268L, 588L, 768L, 792L, 744L, 
  1680L, 684L, 2052L, 672L, 492L, 744L, 768L, 828L, 936L, 840L, 
  5364L, 408L, 528L, 60L, 612L, 684L, 852L, 756L, 972L),
  .Tsp = c(2013, 2017.41666666667, 12), class = "ts")    

plot(data, xlab='Years', ylab = ' Qty ')


# Step 2: Difference data to make data stationary on mean (remove trend)
plot(diff(data),ylab='Differenced Qty')

#Step 3: log transform data to make data stationary on variance
plot(log10(data),ylab='Log (Qty)')

#Step 4: Difference log transform data to make data stationary on both mean and variance
plot(diff(log10(data)),ylab='Differenced Log (Qty)')


# Step 5: Plot ACF and PACF to identify potential AR and MA model
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
acf(ts(diff(log10(data))),main='ACF Qty')
pacf(ts(diff(log10(data))),main='PACF Qty ')

# Step 6: Identification of best fit ARIMA model

require(forecast)
ARIMAfit = auto.arima(log10(data), approximation=FALSE,trace=FALSE)
summary(ARIMAfit)


# Step 6: Forecast sales using the best fit ARIMA model
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
pred = predict(ARIMAfit, n.ahead = 36)
pred
plot(data,type='l',xlim=c(2004,2018),ylim=c(1,1600),xlab = 'Year',ylab = ' Qty ')
lines(10^(pred$pred),col='blue')
lines(10^(pred$pred+2*pred$se),col='orange')
lines(10^(pred$pred-2*pred$se),col='orange')

# Step 7: Plot ACF and PACF for residuals of ARIMA model to ensure no more information is left for extraction
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
acf(ts(ARIMAfit$residuals),main='ACF Residual')
```

Comment: Do `plot(decompose(data)`. There's a strong seasonal component to your data, consider doing something with that.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sorry but it's the first time I used Stackoverflow, Ok thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

You're making it a little more complicated than it needs to be. `auto.arima` will determine the number of AR, MA, and differencing terms to use automatically.

[Here is a link to read more on it.](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7)

Ultimately, if you just want the code for the fit though you could do this

```
library(forecast)
data = ts(data[,2],start = c(2013,1),frequency = 12)
model = auto.arima(data)
```

We can look at the summary of the model to determine which model it fit

```
> summary(model)
Series: dat 
ARIMA(0,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
          ma1
      -0.8501
s.e.   0.0591

sigma^2 estimated as 4166267:  log likelihood=-479.27
AIC=962.53   AICc=962.77   BIC=966.47
```

So, we have ARIMA(0, 1, 1). There is one difference and 1 MA term in the model that it picked automatically.

If we forecast the model we can plot it like so

```
plot(forecast(model,h=12),include=24)
```

[image]

The reason that we don't see the spikes like we did in the previous data is that the model isn't including any seasonal parameters. Looking at  the plot it doesn't seem like the peaks happen in the same time frame. If the peaks are related to some event those need to be included in the model and this could be  done using the xreg parameter having a binary indicator  for the event.

Comment: Please look at my second post

Comment: @TarhouniBilel It's not an error, it just isn't that great of a fit.

Comment: Thanks freind , I will try to add the xreg in the model